# How can I check the response of MQTT when doing testing through Tsung

Tags: load-testing, mqtt, tsung

I am trying to connect to IOTF platform which is based on MQTT for load testing through Tsung, want to know is it possible in Tsung to check the server response when we are configuring xml for mqtt req. I have tried match tag but nothing seems to worked yet.

Comment: What do you mean by response? There isn't really a response to a MQTT publish (apart from the QOS1/2 delivery confirmation)

Comment: I mean if i am using xml in Tsung to load test MQTT with username and password option set to it, but if not able to establish connection , i want to check what response i get from IOTF(using MQTT Protocol)